# Outlook 2007 Add-in Send Update

Tags: vb6, outlook-addin, outlook-2007

Is there any way to trap the Send Update button in Outlook 2007?  I have the following in my IRibbonExtensibily.GetCustomUI():

```
"<customUI xmlns=""http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2006/01/customui"">" & _
"<commands>" & _
"<command idMso=""SendItem"" onAction=""SendAction"" />" & _
"<command idMso=""SendUpdate"" onAction=""SendAction"" />" & _
"</commands>" & _
"</customUI>"
```

When I use the Send Update button from the appointment form my SendAction() method is never called.  It works from the File menu and other locations but, not on the button.  Is there any way to capture this event?

Or...is there some reason (Item leak or something) that I am not catching it?

Update, I'm also trying to capture it using:

```
 Dim WithEvents updateButton As CommandBarButton 
 Set updateButton = Inspector.CommandBars.FindControl(id:=1983, Visible:=False)
```

But, the results are still the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that the only way to capture this button is in the appointmentitem.send() method.  The buttons aren't part of the ribbon or menus so can't be trapped that way.